# using multiple style sheets

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am currently developing an educational website and as part of it want to include web accessibility as a feature. 
I am trying to include a color content changer like seen here http://www.handicap-international.org.uk/OneStopCMS/Core/SelectLayout.aspx? but I cant figure out how to get the page to call several css external style sheets so that the color of the content will change when the link is clicked?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using PHP at all?

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help! I implemented  a second style sheet using the import option but when I click a button that I want to apply the properties of the css all that happens is that the css file opens on the screen the properties are not applied? I am now looking at using javascript so that when a button is pressed it will call the second style sheet which in turn will apply its properties and change the font and color of the site! However I am not having much luck using this method either!

Answer (score 1):

you have two ways to include external CSS,

1. Using the `<link>` element, or
2. Using the @import rule.

Using the `<link>` element:

To make it a persistent stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="somefile.css" media="screen">
```

To make it a preferred stylesheet, add the title attribute:

```
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="compact" href="somefile.css"` media="screen">
```

To make it an alternate stylesheet, add the word "alternate" to the rel attribute.

```
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="compact" href="somefile.css" media="screen">
```

Using an @import rule:

It is possible to include one stylesheet in another using @import. This must be done at the top of any CSS before any rules are declared.

```
Example (in somefile.css): 
@charset UTF-8 
@import "someotherfile.css"
```

This is also possible:

```
<head> 
<style>@import "somefile.css"</style> 
</head>
```

This should be enough to help you understand how to include multiple external style sheets.
Take care and good luck....!!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume the example you posted uses only 1 style sheet that stores multiple css properties. Once you click the link it chooses the appropriate properties for that over arching theme from that single style sheet and disregards the rest.

Given that, why would you want multiple style sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the CSS for anchor tag as unvisited, visited, hover and active:

```
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
     color: #FF0000;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
   color: #00FF00;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #FF00FF;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
     color: #0000FF;
}
```

Comment: You need not to call multiple CSS for that. You can enter above given styles in your main CSS or HTML head style tags.